# How do you display an Uploaded (From Camera Roll) Image in Swift

Tags: swift

So I have just created my first app! It is almost finished! The only problem, I need to get a picture (uploaded from camera roll) into a Ui-Image! Please Help!

Also, I don't want to upload it to PHP or any other database languages. Just want it to stay.

Comment: what does "uploaded from camera roll" mean?

Comment: The user clicks a button and then it opens their camera roll. They then select the photo and it displays on a UI-Image

Comment: Why don't you use a UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to export your Camera Roll image from iPhoto in a standard format, such as png. Here's an [instruction page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19813?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US) for exporting your photo.

Once you have your image in the correct format you can add it to your app's assets. In your Xcode Project Navigator, appears on left when not collapsed (look for a little folder icon), find Assets under your project file. Click on Assets, a new menu will fly out with a '**+**' at the bottom to add a group or image set. Follow the prompts to add your image.

Now that you can access the image from your application you may set it as the source file for a UIImage. Click on the image in your Storyboard. The Image attribute should now show your new photo in the drop down as an option. Select it. Alternatively, you may set the image attribute in your code. Something like this in Swift:

```
let myImage = UIImage(named: "yourImageName")!
imageView.image = myImage
```

**Follow up** to your comment about you image source. You can add a button that opens the user's album or camera. The higher level logic for onButtonClick looks something like this:

```
@IBAction func onButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {
    let actionSheet = UIAlertController(title: "Change Photo", message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    actionSheet.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Album", style: .Default, handler: {action in self.showAlbum()}))

    self.presentViewController(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func showAlbum() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.sourceType = .Camera

    presentViewController(picker, animated:true, completion:nil)
}
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/) are details for the UIImagePickerController()-- You will need a UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to finally set the image.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering me! The only problem is that I was looking for a users camera roll. Like, if they tap a button it opens their camera roll and they can select the image. Next, the image would appear.

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding. You create a button or menu item that opens the user's album. I think this is commonly done with an actionSheet.

Comment: Do you know any way to do this? If you know a tutorial please link me or a website. Thank you once again!

Comment: I didn't mean to leave that comment. Please see my edited answer, thanks!